# Not able to type anything in Xamarin Source code editor

Tags: xamarin-studio

I have installed Xamarin Studio V 5.7 on Mac OSx 10.10.1.
I created a project and tried to edit a source file in the Xamarin Source code editor, nothing gets typed in any of the files from the project.
I re-installed Xamarin studio, restarted mac, nothing worked.
If anyone has faced the problem and has a solution, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Xamarin Studio screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a valid subversion repository towards the root of the file system and XS sees the project as being part of the repository, since the system is based on directory trees. There are a few possible solutions I can think of on the spot:

1. Remove the .svn directory if it's not intended to be there.
2. Move the project into another directory that's not in the scope of the .svn directory.
3. If you aren't going to use Subversion anyway, you can disable the AddIn through the AddIn manager.

There are safety checks in XS in case of invalid subversion repository directories, but this is a case where you can't safely decide whether the solution belongs there or not.

I'll take a look at how I can improve this so that the Editor isn't locked because of this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remedy the issue via disabling the integrated source control for the time being.